# resizing an ntfs-partition without any loss of data, while running ubuntu (studio) from a live usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, gparted

This is my very first question on askubuntu. I know there are quite a few similar threads hanging around here and there, but most of the answers given have either proven to be too technical, or haven't quite worked for me. So, here's my situation:

I've been running ubuntustudio 16.04 from a live usb-stick for a few days now, since my windows 7 ultimate installation suddenly stopped booting after running an update of my antivirus program. I went with the studio-version 'cause I'm interested in trying the various multimedia production software included. One thing that's been bugging me is whether it lacks any functionality in terms of data-recovery etc. as compared to "normal" ubuntu, so any clarification on this point would be appreciated.

Apart from all that:

I only have one properly working usb-stick available (the one that I'm currently running ubuntustudio live from), so creating multiple live usb:s to boot various tools is not an option (helpful as it might have been).

Neither do I have lots of hard drive space available, so whatever I do, I've got to do it without any backups (unsafe as it may be).

I would like to create a partition to resize my 480GB SSD drive, and there install the ubuntustudio OS that I'm currently running live from my 16 GB usb-stick, so that I can then format my stick and create a live usb installation for Windows 7 to see if I can repair it.

When right-clicking on my SSD's icon, I see under "properties" that I 've got 97.9GB free space, which sound pretty accurate. When viewing the same device in G-Parted, I see one partition with 355.92 GiB of used space and 91.21 GiB of unused space, as well as another 1.84 MiB of unallocated space. I had to quit and reopen GParted a few times to finally get to view this information. Inbetween I tried downloading the latest reportedly stable version of ntfs-3g from [here](http://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/), but then I wasn't really sure what to do with it, so I tried typing `sudo apt get install ntfs-3g` from within the terminal, instead. The results weren't any better, though, so I went back to my firefox downloads folder, extracted the ntfs-3g archive, right-clicked on the extracted folder, and chose "Open Terminal Here". Then I typed:

`./configure`

`make`

`sudo make install`

and later I added

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1`

This seems to have finally done the job, since I'm able to see the partition information in G-Parted.

Next step is to create a Partition in order to install ubuntustudio 16.04

What exactly are the steps?

What file-system should the new partition be based upon and how large should it be? (available unused space is, as mentioned, 91.21GiB, according to GParted).

Can it be done "mouse-wise" or is command-typing necessary?

How safe is it (like, statistically)?

PS  My acquaintance with Linux is evidently far from adequate.

PS2 My Windows 7 installation is located on another SSD-Drive, with only 6.07GiB available unused space out of 111.69GiB in total (according to GParted).

Comment: Standard Ubuntu includes NTFS driver by default, not sure about Studio. And normally ntfsfix does not do much, but turns on the chkdsk flag so when you boot Windows it will run chkdsk. NTFS only works well with 30% free space inside the NTFS partition. If you make it less it will slow down and at 10% free just about cannot do a defrag as not enough space. I normally install to a 25GB / (root) partition with 2GB for swap as I have 4GB of RAM or more. Always best to shrink NTFS using Windows tools, especially if it has issues. Can you boot Windows with f8 into repair console?

Comment: 1. Is the driver included even while running ubuntu from a live usb? 2. So ntfsfix had nothing to do with my success in viewing the desired information and is pretty meaningless as long as Windows ain't booting? 3. Can lack of space slow your pc down to the point of not even booting? 4. Where can I find the safest possible guide for lossless partitioning with GParted in a scenario such as mine? 5. F8 won't do anything.

Comment: Lack of space slows system down, but it should boot as long as you have some space. Linux hides 5% just for that reason. There is no such thing as 100% safe way to make major changes to system. That is why we always suggest really good backups before hand.